# serializing java object to json with auto generated names

Tags: java, json

i want to create a json file out of my java objects similar to this structure:

> {"users" :
>
> ```
>  {"1" : 
>      { "ids" : [1,2,3], "names" : ["anton","berta","charlie"] },
>
>  {"2" :
>      { "ids" : [4,5,6], "names" : ["dora","emil","friedrich"] },
> ```

...and so on.

My problem is that i don´t know how to generate the numbers of the second hierarchy. In all of the tutorials i found the hierarchy names are generated by the class names or with annotations but i can´t use this way to create my requested names.

Is there a way to do so without writing a huge method where i generate the json Stirng "by hand"?

Greetz

Comment: By numbers of the second hierarchy, do you mean the string number keys that map to json objects? What do those keys mean? How are you serializing the rest of the structure? If you're using the right options, it might be as simple as having an object contain a map. What do your java objects look like?

Comment: Try [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) it is a library which converts JSON to Java objects directly.

Comment: I get my user data from a stream in a ten minute interval - so the "1" : { "ids" : ... } represent the first ten minute interval of collected data, the "2" : { ... } the second and so on.

Comment: Can you show us your `User` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code required to create each json entry is not that much:

```
public static String toJson(int i, List<User> users) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{\"").append(i).append("\" : { \"ids\" : [");
    for (User user : users)
        sb.append(user.getId()).append(",");
    sb.setCharAt(sb.length() - 1, ']');
    sb.append(", \"names\" : [\"");
    for (User user : users)
        sb.append(user.getName()).append("\",\"");
    return sb.replace(sb.length() - 2, sb.length(),"] } ,").toString();
}
```

With this method in place, adding new users to the list during your time period and assigning a sequential number to each list is a trivial matter.

---

Here's some complete test code and its output:

```
static class User {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;

    public User(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public static String toJson(int i, List<User> users) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{\"").append(i).append("\" : { \"ids\" : [");
    for (User user : users)
        sb.append(user.getId()).append(",");
    sb.setCharAt(sb.length() - 1, ']');
    sb.append(", \"names\" : [\"");
    for (User user : users)
        sb.append(user.getName()).append("\",\"");
    return sb.replace(sb.length() - 2, sb.length(),"] } ,").toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {//throws Exception {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    users.add(new User(1, "anton"));
    users.add(new User(2, "berta"));
    users.add(new User(3, "charlie"));
    System.out.println(toJson(1, users));
 }
```

Output:

```
{"1" : { "ids" : [1,2,3], "names" : ["anton","berta","charlie"] } ,
```

Comment: Nice, that´s what i looked for. Many thanks to you and all others tried to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's take Gson as example:

you may use Gson customize serializer like following (I create class Users, otherwise other List will use MySerializer, which is not expected)

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import com.google.gson.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static class User {
        private List<Integer> ids;
        private List<String> names;

        public User(List<Integer> ids, List<String> names) {
            this.ids = ids;
            this.names = names;
        }
    }

    public static class Users extends ArrayList<User> {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Users users = new Users();
        users.add(new User(Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3), Lists.newArrayList("anton", "berta", "charlie")));
        users.add(new User(Lists.newArrayList(4, 5, 6), Lists.newArrayList("dora", "emil", "friedrich")));

        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Users.class, new MySerializer());
        System.out.printf(gsonBuilder.create().toJson(users));
    }

    public static class MySerializer implements JsonSerializer<Users> {
        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(Users users, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
                jsonObject.add(String.valueOf(i + 1), jsonSerializationContext.serialize(users.get(i)));
            }
            return jsonObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Another simple way is put list into map and then make json, like

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
  public static class User {
    private List<Integer> ids;
    private List<String> names;

    public User(List<Integer> ids, List<String> names) {
      this.ids = ids;
      this.names = names;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
      users.add(new User(Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3), Lists.newArrayList("anton", "berta", "charlie")));
      users.add(new User(Lists.newArrayList(4, 5, 6), Lists.newArrayList("dora", "emil", "friedrich")));

      Map<String, User> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, User>();
      for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
          map.put(String.valueOf(i + 1), users.get(i));
      }

      System.out.printf(new Gson().toJson(map));
  }
}
```